# Using iron-session and deploying in vercel failed

Tags: next.js, vercel

I use nextjs with iron-session and wanted to deploy it on vercel. I followed this tutorial to add iron-session to nextjs so my code is basically exactly like this:

https://codegregg.com/blog/2022/password-protected-nextjs-page/

However I got this message when deploying on vercel:

`500 Internal Server Error.`

When looking more into it I found this error message:

`Error: iron-session: Bad usage. Minimum usage is const session = await getIronSession(req, res, { cookieName: "...", password: "...". Check the usage here: https://github.com/vvo/iron-session` 
I tried out different features and routes of the deployed project and found these:

1. the login and unprotected pages work fine.
2. only the protected pages don't work
3. when entering the password on the login page, and pressing the submit button, nothing happens

Locally my project does work though. So I am not sure what I need to fix from the tutorial code.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue - it was because I hadn't added my environment variables to the vercel deployment. Could be this?

https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables